# Automatically created Sub-folder

Tags: errors, texmaker, dvi

I've problem for days but I can't find the solution

After compiling, the DVI file couldn't opened. a folder named BUILD auto created on the same directory, it contains all the other files like .aux, .dvi, ...

here is the message:

No such file or directory
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (http://www.radicaleye.com) dvips: DVI file can't be opened:
Process exited with error(s)

When opening this BUILD folder, of course I can open the dvi, pdf file... (the tex.file hasn't errors)

I tried to reinstall the latest version of MiKTeX and TeXmaker, GS, GSview, and the problem isn't fixed.

How to make it back normal (DVI, PS, PDF, ... shown in the same folder), please?
(I'm using MiKTeX version 2.9)

Comment: Open TeXmaker: go to Options --> Configure--> Uncheck `Use "build" subdirectory for output files` otherwise all output files will sit in subdirectories for `latex` and `pdflatex` engines.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from TeXmaker 3.4 version

> "an option "Use a 'build' subdirectory for output files" has been added for the (pdf)latex command (the "--output-directory=build" parameter will be automatically added to the (pdf)latex command and texmaker will search the log and pdf files into this subdirectory - see the user manual for more details)" - from [changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)

Open TeXmaker: go to `Options` --> `Configure` --> **Uncheck** `Use "build" subdirectory for output files` otherwise all output files will go to subdirectory.

Note: In future, refer first TeXmaker [documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html), [changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) and it's [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) before posting here